# I want to plot perpendicular vectors in Python

Tags: python, vector, plot

I would like to simply plot perpendicular vectors in 2D. I've implemented 2 ways to plot them in the code below but the vectors don't "look" perpendicular to me when the plots are drawn. If it makes any difference I'm using Spyder.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1=[0,0,4,3]
x2=[0,0,-3,4]
x3=[0,0,3,-4]
soa =np.array([x1,x2,x3]) 
X,Y,U,V = zip(*soa) 
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(X,Y,U,V,angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1)
ax.set_xlim([-10,10])
ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
plt.draw()
plt.show()

import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
lines = [[(0, 1), (4, 3)], [(-3, 4), (3, -4)]]
c = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)])
lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the size of the unit differs on the x and y axes. You need to force them to be equal.

In matplotlib.pyplot, add the line

```
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

just before you show the graph with

```
plt.show()
```

I get this result in the IPython console in Spyder:

[image]

In pylab, add the line

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

at the end. However, these line segments still do not look perpendicular, and that is because they really are not perpendicular. The slope of your first, red line segment is 2/3, so your second, green line segment should have slope -3/2 but it actually has slope -4/3. Perhaps change your line to

```
lines = [[(0, 1), (4, 3)], [(-3, 4), (3, -5)]]
```

(I changed the ending -4 to -5) to get the correct second slope. You get a change from this first figure to the second:

[image]

[image]

and that last does look perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the aspect ratio of the figure canvas.

Use:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
```